# How to search numbers in php mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

How would i search for a random number between two numbers by mysql query.
This is not a valid mysql command this just for understanding.

```
$number = 3600;
$aa = 3300;
$bb = 4000;
$query = "Search for the $number between $aa AND $bb";
```

How would i do this with php and mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `number` BETWEEN '$aa' AND '$bb'
```

See the [manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) for `BETWEEN`.

This is just the MySQL query. How you call it in PHP depends on your framework. E.g. you could use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).